Does Postgres have anything analogous to Microsoft SQL Server's Batch Mode?
In traditional usages of Microsoft SQL Server, exactly one row flows from one operator in a query plan to the next. In Batch Mode, huge performance gains are obtained by moving thousands of rows at a time between operators. SQL Server has supported this since SQL Server 2012. Does Postgres have anything like this?

PostgreSQL doesn't offer built in column-store, but there are 3rd party extensions which support it.  I don't have all of Microsoft's marketing gibberish memorized, if this isn't about their version of column store than please clarify what it is about. - comment from jjanes
No, Postgres does not have Batch mode. - comment from Alexander Petrov
